# Failed to integrate zendesk sdk in android

Tags: android, zendesk, zendesk-app

I am integrating Zandesk sdk in my android app. I am following instructions as mentioned over the zendesk developer site as mentioned in below link

```
https://developer.zendesk.com/embeddables/docs/android-chat-sdk/gettingstarted
```

But when I am trying to add gradle dependency it says Failed to resolved dependency. I am adding below dependency as mentioned on the developer site

```
compile group: 'com.zopim.android', name: 'sdk', version: '1.3.5.1'
```

Further more I tried to down the version as mentioned in versions  list (I thought one of the older versions may work) but same error. Am I missing anything? Did anybody face the same issue? Previous versions of the sdk also mentioned in below link as well

```
https://developer.zendesk.com/embeddables/docs/android-chat-sdk/versions
```

Any help?

Answer (score 1):

After spending sometime, I have found the solution. It was the problem of my side I forgot to add below line of code

```
repositories {
maven { url 'https://zendesk.jfrog.io/zendesk/repo' }
}
```

Posting this answer, it may help other.